# States wise Demographics data API for Unites States with year range

Tags: census

I am working on a dashboard that consists of data for the United States with a trend graph ....Do you know any source or API which provides data with year range?

1. Population

- Trend Graph
- Summary stats

2. Gender distribution

- Trend Graph
- Summary stats

3. Age distribution

- Trend Graph
- Summary stats

4. Education level

- Trend Graph
- Summary stats

5. Household size

- Trend Graph
- Summary stats

6. Urbanization

- Trend Graph
- Summary stats

7. Life expectancy

- Trend Graph
- Summary stats

8. Fertility rate

- Trend Graph
- Summary stats

9. Mortality rate

- Trend Graph
- Summary stats

10. Migration rate

- Trend Graph
- Summary stats

So in this case if there is an API please let me know also it does not matter whether it is paid or free